# List all invites in a guild or multiple guilds (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm looking to fetch all the invites created within a guild or guilds and print all the invites without a command I want it to fetch and print them as soon as the bot is online

How can I do that? Is it possible because I haven't found ANYTHING on the internet that's even close to what I am trying to do

pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs have it right here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.invites).

```py
invites = await guild.invites()
```

You can then add that to a `on_ready` event (for when the bot is online) and iterate over them and print them.